# How to specify time locator's start-ticking timestamp

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

All I want is quite straight forward, I just want the locator ticks to start at a specified timestamp:
`peudo code: locator.set_start_ticking_at( datetime_dummy )`
I have no luck finding anything so far.

Here is the portion of the code for this question:

```
    axes[0].set_xlim(datetime_dummy) # datetime_dummy = '2015-12-25 05:34:00'
    import matplotlib.dates as matdates
    seclocator = matdates.SecondLocator(interval=20) 
    minlocator = matdates.MinuteLocator(interval=1) 
    hourlocator = matdates.HourLocator(interval=12)

    seclocator.MAXTICKS  = 40000
    minlocator.MAXTICKS  = 40000
    hourlocator.MAXTICKS  = 40000

    majorFmt = matdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')  
    minorFmt = matdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')  

    axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(minlocator)
    axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFmt)
    plt.setp(axes[0].xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )

    axes[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(seclocator)
    axes[0].xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorFmt)
    plt.setp(axes[0].xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90 )

    # other codes
    # save fig as a picture
```

The x axis ticks of above code will get me:

[image]

How do I tell the minor locator to align with the major locator?
How do I tell the locators which timestamp to start ticking at?

what I have tried:
`set_xlim` doesn't do the trick
`seclocator.tick_values(datetime_dummy, datetime_dummy1)` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using the `interval` keyword parameter, use [`bysecond`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.SecondLocator) and [`byminute`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MinuteLocator) to specify exactly which seconds and minutes you with to mark. The `bysecond` and `byminute` parameters are used to construct a [dateutil rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#module-dateutil.rrule). The `rrule` generates datetimes which match certain specified patterns (or, one might say, "rules").

For example, `bysecond=[20, 40]` limits the datetimes to those whose `second`s
equal 20 or 40. Thus, below, the minor tick marks only appear for datetimes
whose soconds equal 20 or 40.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as matdates

N = 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(N).astype('<i8').view('M8[s]').tolist()
y = (np.random.random(N)-0.5).cumsum()
ax.plot(x, y)


seclocator = matdates.SecondLocator(bysecond=[20, 40]) 
minlocator = matdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(60))  # range(60) is the default

seclocator.MAXTICKS  = 40000
minlocator.MAXTICKS  = 40000

majorFmt = matdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S')  
minorFmt = matdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')  

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(minlocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFmt)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(seclocator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorFmt)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you thank you! Could you add a more detailed explanation how `bysecond=list` works in your answer? I think I disregarded this parameter while reading the documentation because I did not understand what it did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@unutbu: Many thanks: I've been looking everywhere for the answer to a related problem!

@eliu: I've adapted unutbu's excellent answer to demonstrate how you can define lists (to create different 'dateutil' rules) which give you complete control over which x-ticks are displayed. Try un-commenting each example below in turn and play around with the values to see the effect. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 05:03', '2017-01-01 18:03', freq = 'min')
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)),  index = idx)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Choose which major hour ticks are displayed by creating a 'dateutil' rule e.g.:

# Only use the hours in an explicit list:
# hourlocator = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=[6,12,8])

# Use the hours in a range defined by: Start, Stop, Step:
# hourlocator = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(8,15,2))

# Use every 3rd hour:
# hourlocator = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 3)

# Set the format of the major x-ticks:
majorFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')  

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hourlocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFmt)

#... and ditto to set minor_locators and minor_formatters for minor x-ticks if needed as well)

ax.plot(df.index, df.values, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)

fig.autofmt_xdate() # optional: makes 30 deg tilt on tick labels

plt.show()
```