# matplotlib - xticks in pyplot not set to HH:MM

Tags: python, matplotlib, png

I am trying to reproduce [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219987) with additional requirements such as title, legends, etc. While some of them seem to be met, the labels aren't appearing at all. I need the x-axis to show HH:MM labels every 30 minutes interval. Can you please help me achieve this?

```
figtemp, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9.0, 6.0), dpi=720)
    ax.plot(x1, y1, 'b', linewidth=1)
    xlocator = md.MinuteLocator(interval=30)
    xformatter = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
    plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation='vertical', fontsize=9)
    #
    plt.grid(True)
    title = '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(title, 40))
    plt.title(title, fontsize=12)
    plt.tight_layout(pad=8.0)
    #    
    #plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b', linewidth=1)
    #
    plt.xlabel(axesText[0])
    plt.ylabel(axesText[1])
    #
    #
    if aCondition is True:
        ax.plot(x2, y2, 'r', linewidth=1)
    #
    plt.legend(legends, bbox_to_anchor=[0.0, 0.0], loc='center right')
    #
    plt.savefig('sample.png')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Can you create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` list has timestamp in `HH:MM:SS` format **as a string** already because the function passing data to this plot function had done a `strftime()`. I suppressed that transformation so that the plot function receives a Python date time object.

Now, it works! yay!

Please let me know, if I should delete/close this question as obviously, this is not *directly* related to `matplotlib`.