# How can I fix error "Invalid rrule byxxx generates an empty set." using a MinuteLocator for matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-dateutil

I want to create a plot using Matplotlib to show a time along the x-axis. The following code is a complete minimum workable example:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

times = np.arange(0, 5000, 60)
x = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(val) for val in times]
y = random.sample(range(1, 100), len(x))

formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10)
# locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10, byminute=10)
# locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10, byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50])

plt.clf()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("time [min]")
plt.ylabel("Random number")
plt.show()
```

Along with a `DateFormatter`, it creates the following axis labels:

[image]

However, I want the ticks to be made only at every full 10 minutes, i.e., I want ticks at times 15:30, 15:40, 15:50, etc. and not starting at 15:24. So I tried

```
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10, byminute=10)
```

which gives me an error

> ValueError: Invalid rrule byxxx generates an empty set.

but according to [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MinuteLocator), you also can specify an int value or a list of ints.
But even when trying to use a list of ints

```
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10, byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50])
```

it still gives the same error!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think you need this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219655/how-to-specify-time-locators-start-ticking-timestamp

Comment: I saw that thread. That is how I came to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're listing specific integers, I don't think you need to specify the interval.

Change this:

```
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10, byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50])
```

To this:

```
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50])
```

Comment: Ah yes that works. But why doesn't it work with an int? Maybe the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean 'int' integer or 'int' interval?

Comment: 'int' integer ...

Comment: I think it's just the fact that the syntax of MinuteLocator allows you to specify an interval as in MinuteLocator(interval=10) OR specify minutes as integers MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,10,20,30,40,50]), not both

Comment: This comes down to how things are implemented in [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/6b035517571e63b6a63a493740c5506ec1e5da44/dateutil/rrule.py#L1071). I think if you're going to use `byminute` _and_ an `interval`, you'd need to use the `dtstart` keyword (parsing it a ``datetime` object) that has the same minute epoch as the initial value in `byminute`.

Comment: Although you can't actually pass `dtstart` to `MinuteLocator`, so that's not an option!